# How to see who's blocking my internet connection? fail2ban?

Tags: iptables, fail2ban

I was just running `apt-get dist-upgrade` from a distant ssh console when I lost the connection.

I would like to know which service blocked my connection. I know `fail2ban` is sometime a bit flaky, but I don't know how to check what's the actual iptables rules that may block my internet access.

I tired `/etc/init.d/fail2ban restart`...

Comment: Had the connection been running for a period and then it ended? Are you sure it's an active block or might it just be a failed connection at some point?

Comment: No it just blocked in both way. I was unable to ping outside from my server and I was unable to ping my server from the outside. After the reboot everything was ok.